# System.InvalidOperationException: 'No type reader found for type CommandContext, one must be specified'

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm fairly new to bot dev but know a thing or too about C# however I've been looking for quite some time and still cannot seem to find a solution to my problem. I'm using Discord.NET and my bot was working great until I introduced Discord.Addons.Interactive addon and I don't know how to fix it.

Whenever I run my program I get the error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'No type reader found for type CommandContext, one must be specified'.

Here is my Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
       
    private DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private CommandService _commands;
    private IServiceProvider _services;

    public Program() 
    {
    }

    public async Task MainAsync()
    {

        _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        _commands = new CommandService();

        _services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton(_client)
            .AddSingleton(_commands)
            .AddSingleton<CommandHandler>()
            .AddSingleton<InteractiveService>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        _client.Log += LogAsync;
        _client.Ready += ReadyAsync;

        var tocken = "my_tocken";

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, tocken);
        await _client.StartAsync();

        await _services.GetRequiredService<CommandHandler>().InstallCommandAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    private Task LogAsync(LogMessage msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    private Task ReadyAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Connected as -> [{_client.CurrentUser}]");
        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }
   
}
```

Here is my CommandHandler.cs:

```
public class CommandHandler
{
    private readonly DiscordSocketClient _client;
    private readonly CommandService _commands;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    public CommandHandler(DiscordSocketClient client, CommandService commands, IServiceProvider services, InteractiveService interactions)
    {
        _commands = commands;
        _client = client;
        _services = services;


        _commands.CommandExecuted += CommandExecutedAsync;
        _client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
       
    }

    public async Task InstallCommandAsync()
    {
        await _commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);
    }

    private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage messageParam)
    {
        var message = messageParam as SocketUserMessage;
        var context = new SocketCommandContext(_client, message);

        if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

        int argPos = 0;

        if (message.HasCharPrefix('-', ref argPos))
        {
            await _commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _services);
        }

        
    }


    public async Task CommandExecutedAsync(Optional<CommandInfo> command, ICommandContext context, IResult result)
    {
        if (!command.IsSpecified)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Command failed to execute for [{context.User.Username}] <-> [{result.ErrorReason}]!");
            return;
        }
        if (result.IsSuccess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Command [{command.Value.Name}] execute for [{context.User.Username}]!");
            return;
        }

        await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{context.User.Username} Something went wrong -> [{result}]!");

    }
}
```

If you need anymore information then just let me know.

EDIT:
I found the issue, I had put a CommandContext parameter in one of my commands.
Hope this helps anyone in the future :)

Comment: Sounds like one of your commands has a `CommandContext` as one of its arguments.

Comment: Yup, thank you Anu6is, you were right! :)